# Function isalnum(): unexpected results

Tags: c++

For an assignment, I am using std::isalnum to determine if the input is a letter or a number. The point of the assignment is to create a "dictionary." It works well on small paragraphs, but does horrible on pages of text. Here is the code snippet I am using.

```
 custom::String string;

 std::cin >> string;

 custom::String original = string;                                                
 size_t size = string.Size();                                                  
 char j;                                                                       
 size_t i = 0;                                                                        
 size_t beg = 0;   

 while( i < size)
 {

 j = string[i];

 if(!!std::isalnum(static_cast<unsignedchar>(j)))                     
 {                                                                   
   --size;                                                                  
 }                                                                        

 if( std::isalnum( j ) )                                                    
 {                                                                         
   string[i-beg] = tolower(j);                                            
 }                                                                          

 ++i; 

 }//end while                                                                  

 string.SetSize(size - beg, '\0');
```

Comment: Are you missing a portion of the code? What is that last bracket and `end while` doing there?

Comment: I suppose you can gain some performance by removing one of those `if(std::isalnum(j))`, since one is `else`-case of the other.

Comment: Sorry about that. The code had been edited. Should make sense now.

Comment: You never update `j` in your loop so it uses `string[0]` every time

Comment: It is corrected, but the output is still incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The code presented as I write this, does not make sense as a whole.

However, the calls to `isalnum`, as shown, would only work for plain ASCII, because

- the C character classification functions require non-negative argument, or else `EOF` as argument, and

in order to work for international characters,

- the encoding must be single-byte per character, and
- `setlocale` should have been called prior to using the functions.

Regarding the first of these three points, you can wrap `std::isalnum` like this:

```
using Byte = unsigned char;

auto is_alphanumeric( char const ch )
    -> bool
{ return !!std::isalnum( static_cast<Byte>( ch ) ); }
```

where the `!!` is just to silence a sillywarning from Visual C++ (warning about "performance", of all things).

Disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands.

---

Addendum: if you don't have a C++11 compiler, but only C++03,

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;

bool is_alphanumeric( char const ch )
{
    return !!std::isalnum( static_cast<Byte>( ch ) );
}
```

As Bjarne remarked, C++11 feels like a whole new language! ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the sloppiness. I have edited it so it should make more sense. Also, the code is only reading plain ASCII.

Comment: Could you explain the code for C++11 and how it works. I don't quite follow it.

Comment: It works the same as the code for C++03, just using new C++11 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a solution to the problem. I noticed that isalnum did take care of some non alpha-numerics, but not all the time. Since the code above is part of a function, I called it multiple times with refined results given each time. I then came up with a do while loop that stores the string's size, calls the function, stores the new size, and compares them. If they are not the same it means that there is a chance that it needs to be called again. If they are the same, then the string has been fully cleaned. I am guessing that the reason isalnum was not working well was because I was reading in several chapters of a book into the string. Here is my code:

```
custom::string abc;
std::cin >> abc;

size_t first = 0;                                                           
size_t second = 0;                                                          

//clean the word                                                            
do{                                                                         
  first = abc.Size();                                                       
  Cleanup(abc);                                                             
  second = abc.Size();                                                      
}while(first != second);
```